# images are not working on my local server in A-frame

Tags: javascript, html, image, aframe

I'm trying since a week now to get images working on the local server. I uploaded the images in my folder. Sometimes one or two random image is working. I don't see any different to the other image in the code. Could someone help me? im really desperate.

```
    <a-assets>

            <audio
            id="click-sound"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            src="https://cdn.aframe.io/360-image-gallery-boilerplate/audio/click.ogg"></audio>

            <img id="bloom" src="bloom.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
            <img id="selbst" scr="pixfrog.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
            <img id="herzderfi" scr="herzderfi.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
            <img id="fisher" scr="fisher.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous"/>


        

<!--Drawings-->
        
            <img id="1" scr="klein1.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
            <img id="2" scr="draw/2.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
            <img id="3" scr="draw/3.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
            <img id="4" scr="draw/4.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
            <img id="5" scr="draw/5.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
            <img id="6" scr="draw/6.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
            <img id="7" scr="draw/7.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
            <img id="8" scr="draw/8.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
            <img id="9" scr="draw/9.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
        </a-assets>
```

and
´´´

```
      <a-image src="#bloom" class="clickable" position="-7 -1 -5" height="5" width="5"></a-image>
      <a-image src="#herzderfi" class="clickable" position="0.5 -0.9 -8" height="5" width="5"></a-image>
      <a-image scr="#selbst" class="clickable" position="5 -1 5" height="2.5" width="1.25"></a-image>
      <a-image scr="#fisher" class="clickable" position="0 -1 0" height="3" width="5"></a-image>
      <a-image scr="#selbst" class="clickable" position="5 -1 5" height="2.5" width="1.25" material="src: #selbst"></a-image>


      <a-plane class="clickable" color="white" material="shader:flat;" position="-5 -3 -5" ></a-plane>




      <a-plane
        toggle-menu="#main-menu"
        class="clickable"
        position="4 0 2"
        height="0.5"
        width="1.5"
        color="red"
        material="shader: flat; src: #pixfrog"
        text="value: Menu One; align: center; width: 4;"
        side="double"
      ></a-plane>
    </a-entity>
```

´´´

Answer (score 0):

What are you using as a server? Do you by any chance access the html by **file://** ? (simply double-clicking the file). This may cause issues when running A-Frame.

> Try not to open the project using the file:// protocol which does not provide a domain; absolute and relative URLs may not work. ([source](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/installation.html#use-a-local-server))

---

Are you sure the images are accessible at the path specified in src?

> `<img id="bloom" src="bloom.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous"/>`

This may (or may not depending on your server settings) point to the file at the same location as the **.html** file.

Also can you check the console (F12 on chrome) for something like **Error 404** or perhaps something like:
`%ccore:a-assets:warn %cAsset loading timed out in %c ... 3000 ms`

This would mean the image resource cannot be found or took too long to load.

---

Please find the working example below. Maybe it will help:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-assets>
      <img id="myImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/92/A-Frame_logo.png">
    </a-assets>
    
    <a-plane
        material="shader: flat; src: #myImage"
        position="0 1.6 -1"
        toggle-menu="#main-menu"
        class="clickable"
        height="0.5"
        width="1.5"
        color="red"
        text="value: Menu One; align: center; width: 4;"
        side="double"
      ></a-plane>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks so much for the answer! I figured out that it was a really stupid mistake of me ! I wrote most of the time scr and not src ! Thanks a lot for helping!